# Как заставить Gralde проект собираеться оффлайн?

Tags: gradle, offline

У меня задача - собирать gradle проекты из исходников без интернета. Предварительно выкачав все зависимости. Для этого я сначала собираю проект онлайн, потом примитивно копирую папку ~/.gradle в $PROJECT_DIR/grld после чего для тестирования делаю `gradle --stop` очищаю ~/.gradle отключаю Интернет и запускаю сборку проекта следующим скриптом (У меня Gradle 5.0)

```
cp -r ./grdl/* ~/.gradle
cd RSyntaxTextArea
gradle --offline clean build
```

Всё срабатывает хорошо и проект собирается из исходников. Но когда я переношу на другую машину конфигурации: `Linux + JDK 11 + Gragle 5.0` то три проекта из четырёх не собираются. Например проект `git clone --depth 1 --branch 3.0.0 https://github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea.git` при переносе всего на другую машину написал:

```
./build.sh
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':RSyntaxTextArea'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':RSyntaxTextArea:classpath'.
   > Could not download coveralls-gradle-plugin.jar (org.kt3k.gradle.plugin:coveralls-gradle-plugin:2.8.2): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download httpmime.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download org.eclipse.jgit.jar (org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:3.6.0.201412230720-r): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download http-builder.jar (org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download httpclient.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download jsch.jar (com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.50): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download JavaEWAH.jar (com.googlecode.javaewah:JavaEWAH:0.7.9): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download json-lib-jdk15.jar (net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download nekohtml.jar (net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.16): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download xml-resolver.jar (xml-resolver:xml-resolver:1.2): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download httpcore.jar (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download commons-beanutils.jar (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.0): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download commons-logging.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download commons-codec.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download commons-collections.jar (commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download ezmorph.jar (net.sf.ezmorph:ezmorph:1.0.6): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download commons-lang.jar (commons-lang:commons-lang:2.4): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download xercesImpl.jar (xerces:xercesImpl:2.9.1): No cached version available for offline mode
   > Could not download xml-apis.jar (xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.04): No cached version available for offline mode
```

А на своей машине собирается нормально. А вот проект `git clone --depth 1 --branch 0.27 https://github.com/JFormDesigner/FlatLaf.git` собирается оффлайн и на своей и на чужой машине одинаково хорошо. Вероятно я не понимаю как работает кеш gradle. Не могли бы Вы помочь мне собирать gradle проекты оффлайн? При этом я могу использовать любую версию Gradle, но ограничена Linux + JDK 11.

**UPD:**
Мне подсказали, что кеш невалидный потому что пути к ~/.gradle на разных машинах разные потому что username разный (например katya12 и katya2 ) и порекоммендовали перейти на версию 6.1 (подробности тут https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1338 ) но версия 6.1 не хочет собирать (онлайн) данный проект, пишет:

```
> Plugin with id 'osgi' not found.
```

Версия 7.2 тоже не хочет собирать (онлайн) данный проект но пишет другую ошибку:

```
Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [junit:junit:4.12] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Получается надо править билд файлы чтобы собрать градлом версии выше пятой. Помогите пожалуйста?

**UPD2**: мне подсказали, что в шестой версии поддержка osgi плагина была прекращена, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#the_osgi_plugin_has_been_removed и я пытаюсь подключить https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.blindpirate.osgi плагин вот так: https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/cb427be40dfb43030eaca6e3fc71dd2e , но у меня градл пишет ошибку:

```
> Plugin with id 'com.github.blindpirate.osgi' not found.
```

К сожалению я плохо знаю градл, не могли бы Вы направить меня?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавлять плагин в `build.gradle` каждого субпроекта, вместо того, чтобы в орневом `build.gradle` добавлять в секцию `"subprojects {..."`.

Например, как это сделано тут:

```
git clone github.com/bobbylight/RSyntaxTextArea.git
```

(подключается плагин: "biz.aQute.bnd.builder").